# jQuery .inArray question

Tags: jquery, arrays

I want to check if my row id is within in an array. If I set a fixed value to myindex it works but as it is below it always returns the FALSE value.Thank you.

```
$('#stripeMeSubSubCat tr').each(function(){
    myindex = $.trim($(this).closest("tr").attr("id"));

    var array = [ 0, 52, 53 ];

    alert(myindex);
    alert(array);

    if ((jQuery.inArray(myindex, array)) == -1) {
        var equal = "FALSE";
    } else {
        var equal = "TRUE";
    }
    alert(equal); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the string variable ( myindex ) into int using parseInt function ..

Answer (score 0):

```
var  myindex = +$.trim($(this).closest("tr").attr("id"));
```